# How to draw a pyramid with arrows in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I need help with a diagram for my thesis. I want to recreate this diagram [image]

This is my Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
matrix,shapes.symbols}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}


\node [single arrow, draw,fill=white!20, rotate=90] at (-6,1.7) {Abstraktionsebene};
\node [single arrow, draw,fill=white!20, rotate=270] at (-7,1.7) {Datenvolumen};%scale=2.25 ,yshift=10ex, align=center,


\coordinate (A) at (-5,0) {};
\coordinate (B) at ( 5,0) {};
\coordinate (C) at (0,5) {};
\draw[name path=AC] (A) -- (C);
\draw[name path=BC] (B) -- (C);
\foreach \y/\A in 
    {0/Fusion auf Rohdatenebene,
    1/Fusion auf Merkmalsebene,
    2/Fusion auf Objektebene} { %0/G,1/F,2/E,3/D,4/C,5/B,6/A
    \path[name path=horiz] (A|-0,\y) -- (B|-0,\y);
    \draw[name intersections={of=AC and horiz,by=P},
    name intersections={of=BC and horiz,by=Q}] (P) -- (Q)
    node[midway,above] {\A};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: For starters, add the shapes.arrows tikzlibrary, and your code should run.

Comment: It does run, but it doesn't give me the result in the diagramm above. I couldn't get the same size of both arrows

Answer (score 4):

- To have the arrows have the same size, specify its `minimum width` and `minimum height`.
- To have them be aligned at the same height, one solution is changing their `anchor` point.

For example, define:

```
\node [single arrow, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=5cm, draw, 
       anchor=west,rotate=90] at (-6,0) {Abstraktionsebene};
\node [single arrow, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=5cm, draw, 
       anchor=east,rotate=270] at (6,0) {Datenvolumen};
```

Result:
[image]

Here are the anchor points for the `single arrow`:
[image]

Comment: it works thank you for your help !